# Questions about Right-Hand Rule Maze Solver

Tags: java, maze

I'm trying to make a program that solves any 12 * 12 maze by using right-hand rule.
I have some questions about this program. 'X' represents current position, '#' represents walls, '.' represents the way that X can go.

1. Keep Updating X's location on outcome.

I want user to see the way how X follows right wall(represented as # in my codes). I think I have to make delays to the output, and update the output but I don't know how to code these situations. I want to update output like this: as the X goes on the way, it will delete previous 'X' and change it back to '.'. Is there any ways to do this?

2. There are errors on my code.

If I use my algorithm for *maze1*, X replaces # which was not I intended. For *maze2*, it doesn't even work. I think my algorithm makes an error when there are 3 #s surrounding X. Is there any possible way to solve this problem?

Here's my codes for 'Maze Traversal Program.'

```
public class MazeTraversalProgram {
    private static int row, column;
    private static String direction = "right";

private static char maze1 [] [] = {
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','.','.','.','#'},
    {'.','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','#','#','.','#'},
    {'#','#','#','.','#','.','.','.','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','.','#','#','#','.','#','.','.'},
    {'#','#','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','.','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','#','#','.','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','#'},
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'}};

private static char maze2 [] [] = {
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','.','#'},
    {'#','.','#','.','#','.','#','#','#','#','.','#'},
    {'#','#','#','.','#','.','.','.','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','.','#','#','#','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','#','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','.','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','.'},
    {'#','#','#','#','.','#','.','#','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','.','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','#','.','#'},
    {'#','.','#','#','#','#','#','#','.','#','.','#'},
    {'.','.','#','.','.','.','.','#','.','.','.','#'},
    {'#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#'}};

private static void printMaze (char [] [] maze) {
    for (int i = 0; i<maze.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<maze[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(maze [i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
}

//starts the maze - for loop look at first column go down by each row

private static void goForward (char [] [] maze) {
    if (direction == "right") {
        maze[column][row] = '.';
        row++;
        maze[column][row] = 'X';
        direction = "right";
    } else if (direction == "up") {
        maze[column][row] = '.';
        column--;
        maze[column][row] = 'X';
        direction = "up";
    } else if (direction == "left") {
        maze[column][row] = '.';
        row--;
        maze[column][row] = 'X';
        direction = "left";
    } else if (direction == "down") {
        maze[column][row] = '.';
        column++;
        maze[column][row] = 'X';
        direction = "down";
    }
}
private static boolean wallOnRight (char [] [] maze) {
    if (direction == "right" && maze[column+1][row] == '#') {
        return true;
    }
    else if (direction == "up" && maze[column][row+1] == '#') {
        return true;
    }
    else if (direction == "left" && maze[column-1][row] == '#') {
        return true;
    }
    else if (direction == "down" && maze[column][row-1] == '#') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean wallOnFront (char [] [] maze) {
    if (direction == "right" && maze[column][row+1] == '#') {
        return true;
    }
    else if (direction == "up" && maze[column-1][row] == '#') {
        return true;
    }
    else if (direction == "left" && maze[column][row-1] == '#') {
        return true;
    }
    else if (direction == "down" && maze[column+1][row] == '#') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static void turnCounterC () {
    if (direction == "right") {
        direction = "up";
    } else if (direction == "up") {
        direction = "left";
    } else if (direction == "left") {
        direction = "down";
    } else if (direction == "down") {
        direction = "right";
    }
}

private static void turnC () {
    if (direction == "right") {
        direction = "down";
    } else if (direction == "up") {
        direction = "right";
    } else if (direction == "left") {
        direction = "up";
    } else if (direction == "down") {
        direction = "left";
    }
}


private static void traverseMaze (char [] [] maze){

    int count = 0;

    if (count == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            if (maze[i][0] == '.'){                 // array[y,column | ][x,row --- ]
                maze[i][0] = 'X';
                column = i; row = 0;
            }
        }
        count++;
    }

    if (wallOnRight(maze) && wallOnFront(maze)){
        turnCounterC();
    } else if (!wallOnRight(maze)) {
        turnC();
    }
    goForward(maze);
    if (maze[11][row] == 'X') {
        maze[11][row] = 'X';
    } else {
        traverseMaze(maze);
    }
}

public static void main (String [] args) {
    printMaze(maze1);
    traverseMaze(maze1);
    printMaze(maze1);
    printMaze(maze2);
    traverseMaze(maze2);
    printMaze(maze2);
}

}
```

I'm so sorry if you can't understand my English, I'm not native.
Also thank you whoever will answer my questions!

Have a nice day :D:D

Comment: To show current position, when you print it:
if ( currentPos(i,j)
 System.out.print('X' + " ");
else
 System.out.print(maze [i][j] + " ");

Comment: Maybe instead of a dot use a ^,<,>,v to show position and direction as a single character?

Comment: Using `==` on strings is a bad idea, though it may not be an issue here because all the strings are literals. I would suggest using an `enum` for the directions, anyway.

Comment: Usually two dimensional arrays are addressed maze[row][column]. For printMaze, i is row, and j is column so this is correct. For the rest, it is very confusing.

Comment: @AndyMan Thanks for your comment. Thanks to you, I realized I messed row and column up, so I corrected them! :D

Comment: @kaya3 I will keep on mind that it's bad idea to use == on strings. Since I really don't know how enum works, I'll study it for next time. Thank you.